# Get user information on NextJS app after Keycloak login on Kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, keycloak

I have been trying to get the authenticated user information on my NextJS app after being redirected to it on a successful **Keycloak** login on a different tab at `localhost:8080/auth`.

The ingress (entry point) is what checks for authenticated users on Kuberentes and then redirects it to the application. My intention is to get the user info on my `index.tsx` page using `@react-keycloak/ssr`.

So far I have this in my `app.tsx`:

```
const keycloakCfg = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: 'master',
  clientId: 'account-console',
}

interface InitialProps {
  cookies: unknown
}

export default function MyApp(props: AppProps & InitialProps) {
  const { Component, pageProps, cookies } = props;
  const initOptions = {
    checkLoginIframe: false
  }


  return (
    <>
    <SSRKeycloakProvider
      keycloakConfig={keycloakCfg}
      persistor={SSRCookies(cookies)}
      initOptions={initOptions}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SSRKeycloakProvider>
    </>
  );
}

function parseCookies(req?: IncomingMessage) {
  if (!req || !req.headers) {
    return {}
  }
  return cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '')
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context: AppContext) => {
  // Extract cookies from AppContext
  return {
    cookies: parseCookies(context?.ctx?.req),
  }
}
```

And inside my `index.tsx` I have:

```
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak<KeycloakInstance>();
  const parsedToken: ParsedToken | undefined = keycloak?.tokenParsed;

   console.log(keycloak?.authenticated)
    keycloak?.authenticated || (keycloak && parsedToken)
    ? console.log(parsedToken)
    : console.log('error logging in');
```

Issue is even after logging in from `localhost:8080/auth` - still get the error message.

Currently the following flow happens after logging in a separate tab:

1. I go to localhost:3000
2. After the page loads it gets redirected to:
   http://localhost:3000/#error=invalid_request&error_description=Missing+parameter%3A+code_challenge_method&state=8c761520-8aeb-4365-934b-076d8c1d317c
3. After staying on the above link for 1-2 seconds it goes back to `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

```
const initOptions = {
    checkLoginIframe: false,
    pkceMethod: 'S256'`
  }
```

if you have error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[change settings realm user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bupvZ.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem `Missing parameter: code_challenge_method` will solve `pkceMethod` configuration:

```
  const initOptions = {
    checkLoginIframe: false,
    pkceMethod: 'S256'`
  }
```

Comment: thanks, now I am getting a new error: 

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a chat, where I will solve all your problems. Please accept answer and open another question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example